# React adding child outside render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

The title could be clearer, but this is really the best I could come up with, sorry.

So, I am trying to create a filtered table component in React. However, I want the filter to be defined independently from the definition of the table itself. So, here is what I am doing.

I created a Filter component:

```
var Filter = React.createClass({
  handleChange : function (value) {
    this.props.updateTable(this.props.columnName,value);
  },
  render : function () {
    //an input that will report its value to this.handleChange
  }
});
```

Then, I create a Table component:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  filterChanged : function (column, value) {
    //this will be wired as a updateTable prop for the Filter
  },
  render : function () {
    //I am trying not to define a filter here,
    //I am trying to use the previously-defined Filter component.
    //I want the Table component to remain generic and re-usable,
    //with  optional filters.
    var thisComponent = this;
    //I can have as many filters as I want.
    var filterToRender = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
      var filterUI;
      if (child.type.displayName === 'Filter') {
        filterUI = React.cloneElement(child, {updateTable : thisComponent.filterChanged});
      }
      return (<div>{filterUI}</div>);
    });
    //along with the rest of the table UI,
    return (<div>
      <table>bla bla</table>
      {filterToRender}
    </div>);
  }
});
```

Then, in my main page, I render it like this:

```
ReactDOM.render( (<Table>
  <Filter columnName='status'></Filter>
</Table>), document.getElementById('appHolder'));
```

It renders fine. The change functions also seem to be wired fine. However, I find that every time the filter value is changed, it triggers the Table's filterChanged method, increasing number of times. First change, it will trigger 2 times; second change, 6 times; 3rd change, 14 times.

Weird and uncanny. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: code looks fine, can you publish an example where the bug can be reproduced ?

Comment: Shouldn´t you be able to just `this.prop.children.map(...)` ? Maybe it is also an issue with the `<Filter />`s not having a `key`? Though I also can´t really pin down an obvious mistake in your code...

Answer (score 0):

The above procedure for doing things is correct as far as React is concerned. The bug I was getting was due to another framework (Materialize) that uses a jquery plugin to initialize some components. Since it mutates the DOM, I need to manually make sure the onChange events are properly attached to the right node.

Fwiw, I was attaching the `onChange` to `this.handleChange` in a drop-down list in the `ComponentDidMount` **and** `ComponentDidUpdate` of the `Filter` component. Removing initialization from `ComponentDidUpdate`, solved the problem. This, because multiple instances of `handleChange` were being bound to the `onChange` event each time the component updated.